# Proof that $(AA^{-1}=I) \Rightarrow (AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove a pretty simple problem - commutativity of multiplication of matrix and its inverse.

But I'm not sure, if my proof is correct, because I'm not very experienced. Could you, please, take a look at it?

---

#### My proof:

- We know, that $AA^{-1}=I$, where $I$ is an identity matrix and $A^{-1}$ is an inverse matrix.
- I want to prove, that it implies $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A$

\begin{align}
AA^{-1}&=I\\
AA^{-1}A&=IA\\
AX&=IA \tag{$X=A^{-1}A$}\\
AX&=A
\end{align}
At this point we can see, that $X$ must be a multiplicative identity for matrix $A \Rightarrow X$  must be an identity matrix $I$.

\begin{align}
X = A^{-1}A &= I\\
\underline{\underline{AA^{-1} = I = A^{-1}A}}
\end{align}

Comment: How do you have $A^{-1}$ defined?  Is $A$ a square matrix?  It is in general not true for nonsquare matrices that if $AB=I$ that $BA=I$, so the fact that $A$ is square must come into play somehow in the proof.

Comment: Further, the fact that $AX=A$ does not imply that $X$ is an identity matrix.  (*It only implies this if $A$ is invertible, but the proof would require left-multiplication by $A^{-1}$ to cancel out, but that would be circular logic since you are explicitly trying to show $A^{-1}A=I$*)

Comment: @JMoravitz $A^{-1}$ is supposed to be an inverse matrix. I'll add that info into the question

Comment: @JMoravitz yes, it's usually defined by $AA^{-1}=I=A^{-1}A$. I thought, that the other part of the equation ($I = A^{-1}A$) could be deduced from the first one, so that it could be omitted in the definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your claim is not quite true. Consider the example
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Suppose $A, B$ are  square matrices such that $AB = I$. Observe
\begin{align}
BA= BIA= BA BA = (BA)^2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ BA(I-BA) = 0.
\end{align}
Moreover, using the fact that $AB$ is invertible implies $A$ and $B$ are invertible (which is true only in finite dimensional vector spaces), then it follows
\begin{align}
I-BA=0. 
\end{align}

Note: we have used the fact that $A, B$ are square matrices when we insert $I$ between $BA$.